# Rails: How to stop refreshing a page with two objects paginated in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, pagination

I have implemented the will_paginate plug in on RoR project. The will_paginate is done in two objects of the same page, but once any of them gets clicked, the whole page refreshes, and shows the page at the top of view.

How can I make so that after I click the pagination bar, the pagination changes but no refresh happens, or even if refresh happens, it shows the part of the page (div) that this pagination effects?

Is there any possible jquery/ajax way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. In your click event you must insert "e.preventDefault()" before the function that retrive the data:

```
$('#yourelement').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   //your code
});
```

Don't forget the "e" param in the handler.

Comment: What do you mean by "the function that retrieve the data"? I only have a call to the view for the pagination `<%= will_paginate %>`

Comment: Ah you didn't retrive the data via Ajax call? Your function create the pagination? You must attach the event to the items of the pager. Can your post the HTML markup creater by the function please?